# What is the real meaning of "terura"?

Tags: word-usage

According to ReVo

> 1.TEZ
>   Timegiga: terura akcidento; terura estas la stato de la aferojZ; tiuj kalumnioj donis terurajn fruktojnZ.
>
> 2.
>   (figure) Tre forta: ŝi havis teruran malamon kontraŭ liZ

According to PIV

> 1 Tia, ke ĝi elvokas teruron: terura estas tiu ĉi lokoZ; ili havis teruran aspektonZ; ili rakontis terurajn historiojn pri rabobirdojZ; kiam la kuracisto kun la terura ekmovo de la ŝultroj diros al vi: Homa helpo estas vana!Z; tiuj kalumnioj donis terurajn fruktojnZ; terura estas la stato de la aferojZ; ĉio supermezura estas teruraZ.
>
> 2 (f) Tre forta: ŝi havis teruran malamon kontraŭ la pli junaZ.

Still, a lot of people seem to be using "terura" in the sense of "terrible" in English, so it means "tre malbona" "aĉa", which is not related to fear. Is this an erroneous use?

Comment: Like in the Ana Pana course; "Ilia elparolo estis terura"; I don't think their pronunciation was causing fear, or was very strong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First note that the also in English, the original meaning of *terrible* is 'causing fear'. The usage has shifted quite a lot in English, so that nowadays it is used very often in the sense of 'very bad', even when there is no relation to fear. Originally, this was considered metaphorical use, i.e. you compare something bad to something causing fear in a metaphorical way, even if it does not really cause fear. But in English this usage of *terrible* has become so common that people no longer feel it to be a metaphor, but just consider it to be one of the basic meanings of *terrible*.

In Esperanto, *terura* is still mainly used related to things that cause some kind of fear, so that when it is used for something that is just bad without actually causing fear, many speakers would still feel this to be a metaphorical use.

Comment: Personally, I would translate "terura" as "terrifying," but it all comes down to the reader.